# I'm trying to combine an audio file and a video file using ffmpeg and it's not working

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I've already asked a question like this and the answer was to put the file name into quotes, I'm doing that for this problem but it's not working. I think it might be the way I'm writing it, is this the correct way of writing it?

```
ffmpeg -i "♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk1o.mp4" \
       -i "♫ 'Diamond-Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk1o.webm" \
       -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental DiamondSword.mp4
```

Here's the output

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk1o.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-11-25 08:57:19
  Duration: 00:03:23.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 821 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 15 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-11-25 08:57:19
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
♫: No such file or directory
```

And here are the file names

```
♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk1o.mp4
♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk1o.webm
```

EDIT:

```
ffmpeg -i "♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk10.mp4" \ -i "♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk10.webm" \
> c:v -c:a aac -strict experimental DiamondSword.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
♫ 'Diamond Sword' - Minecraft Parody of Demons ♫ [REMASTERED]-jFHGx8vkk10.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you show the complete command and terminal output with this command? Pastebin will help with this....

Comment: Quote your filenames. You quoted the first filename but not the second.

Comment: Done, all the output is in the question and that is the whole command @andrew.46

Comment: That was a mistake I made when writing it into the question details, in my command I included " in both of them, I guess those are the kinds of mistakes you make when writing at 11 pm @muru

Comment: @Sol33t303 I don't believe that. Your command output is consistent with the command you originally had. If you're writing at 11 pm, then double check the command you actually executed as well. Then triple check it.

Comment: @muru I reentered the command correctly and it still didn't work, I will put the command I just put in just now and the output into an edit at the bottom of the question. (btw how do you get the text to appear on a gray background?)

Comment: @Sol33t303 select the text and press Ctrl+K

Comment: @muru ok, I've added the command and the output now. (thanks for telling me how to put text on a grey background)

Comment: I think you should start using tab completion to get the filename. You said `o` and then typed `0`.

Comment: @muru oh, I didn't notice that, i probably should. Nevertheless, it still refuses to work. at the bottom of the output, it now says [NULL @ 0x250aa20] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -i'
 -i: Invalid argument

Comment: That's probably because you typed `\ -i`.

Comment: @muru i actually thought i needed that, when i used ffmpeg before it worked with that from what i remember (last i used it was a few weeks ago) but i removed it and now says [NULL @ 0x1256f60] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'c:v'
c:v: Invalid argument

Comment: which would be because your original command had `-c:v` and now it has `c:v`. Seriously, get off the keyboard and call for help.

Comment: @muru i tried it with and without the - but it still had the same output either way.

Comment: @muru nevermind, the output was actually [NULL @ 0x11acf60] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'aac'
aac: Invalid argument
(i'm pretty sure at this point i need to check to see if my hands and eyes are connected to the right part in my brain)